# Redux Saga Implementing old Redux Thunk Actions

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

(N00B alert) I'm trying to implement the following redux-thunk actions w/ redux-saga (where `fetch` is [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch)):

```
export function addPostRequest(post) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`${baseURL}/api/addPost`, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        post: {
          name: post.name,
          title: post.title,
          content: post.content,
        },
      }),
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => dispatch(addPost(res.post))).catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
}

export function fetchPosts() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetch(`${baseURL}/api/getPosts`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => dispatch(addPosts(response.posts)));
  };
}
```

and I've tried (probably horribly incorrect) variations on the following to no avail (I realize the fork calls shouldn't contain anon generator functions as I have them set up for sake of clarity but I was prototyping so I wasn't worried about clarity yet):

```
function callApi(url, requestObj = {}) {
  return fetch(url, requestObj)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => response)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function *fetchPosts() {
  while (true) {
    yield take(ActionTypes.FETCH_POSTS);
    const posts = yield fork(function *() { //eslint-disable-line
      const result = yield call(callApi, `${baseURL}/api/getPosts`);
      return result.posts;
    });
    yield put(Actions.addPosts(posts));
  }
}


function *addPostRequest() {
  while (true) {
    const post = yield take(ActionTypes.ADD_POST_REQUEST);
    yield fork(function *(post) { //eslint-disable-line
      yield call(callApi, `${baseURL}/api/addPost`, {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          post: {
            name: post.name,
            title: post.title,
            content: post.content,
          },
        }),
        headers: new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
      });
    }, post);
    yield put(Actions.addPost(post));
  }
}

export default function *() {
  yield [
    fork(fetchPosts),
    fork(addPostRequest),
  ];
}
```

and the default function is called on the server side after the store is initialized (where `sagaMiddleware` is exported by

```
function errorHandler(error, getState) {
  console.error(error);
  console.debug('current state', getState());
}

export const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, reduxCatch(errorHandler)),
    typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.devToolsExtension !== 'undefined' ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f,
  ));
  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers/post.reducer', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('../reducers/post.reducer'); //eslint-disable-line
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

):

```
const store = configureStore(initialState);
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

fetchComponentData(store.dispatch, renderProps.components, renderProps.params)
  .then(() => {
    const createElement = (Component, props) => (
      <Component
        {...props}
        radiumConfig={{ userAgent: req.headers['user-agent'] }}
      />
    );
    const initialView = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterContext {...renderProps} createElement={createElement} />
      </Provider>
    );
    const finalState = store.getState().toJS();

    res.status(200).end(renderFullPage(initialView, finalState, getFilename()));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.end(renderFullPage(`Error: ${err}`, {}, getFilename()));
  });
```

and on the client side:

```
const store = configureStore(fromJS(window.__INITIAL_STATE__)); 
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState(state) {
    return state.get('route').toJS();
  },
});
```

UPDATE: Here are the logs upon calling the `FETCH_POSTS` action when the page is rendered server-side (this is a universal/isomorphic app) the data in the arrays are meant to be just random keyboard-smashing :P :

```
    Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `posts` of type `Immutable.Map` supplied to `PostContainer`, expected an Immutable.js List. Check the render method of `Connect(PostContainer)`.
    Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `posts` of type `Immutable.Map` supplied to `PostListView`, expected an Immutable.js List. Check the render method of `Connect(PostListView)`.
    Warning: Using Maps as children is not yet fully supported. It is an experimental feature that might be removed. Convert it to a sequence / iterable of keyed ReactElements instead.
    Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `post` of type `object` supplied to `PostListItem`, expected an Immutable.js Iterable. Check the render method of `PostListView`.
    Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `post` of type `function` supplied to `PostListItem`, expected an Immutable.js Iterable. Check the render method of `PostListView`.
    Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `post` of type `string` supplied to `PostListItem`, expected an Immutable.js Iterable. Check the render method of `PostListView`.
    Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `post` of type `boolean` supplied to `PostListItem`, expected an Immutable.js Iterable. Check the render method of `PostListView`.
    Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `post` of type `number` supplied to `PostListItem`, expected an Immutable.js Iterable. Check the render method of `PostListView`.
    Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `post.name` was not specified in `PostListItem`. Check the render method of `PostListView`.
    webpack built 4e1f2a99c3c358612ecd in 6391ms
    webpack building...
    webpack built 4e1f2a99c3c358612ecd in 443ms
    [ { id: 'cino38mfc0000mrrfdyn8v5k0',
        name: 'sdf',
        title: 'dfdfdh',
        content: 'dfhdfh',
        slug: 'dfdfdh',
        dateadded: '2016-05-01T04:39:36.840Z',
        updateddate: null },
      { id: 'cinmhus6x0000mtrfubcw3eur',
        name: 'sdf',
        title: 'dfhsdfh',
        content: '`sdgdsgd',
        slug: 'dfhsdfh',
        dateadded: '2016-04-30T01:53:13.017Z',
        updateddate: null },
      { id: 'cinmgl1wv000140rf5fdizqsl',
        name: 'sdgsdg',
        title: 'fssddsg',
        content: 'fdfhdfh',
        slug: 'fssddsg',
        dateadded: '2016-04-30T01:17:39.439Z',
        updateddate: null } ]
    [ { id: 'cino38mfc0000mrrfdyn8v5k0',
        name: 'sdf',
        title: 'dfdfdh',
        content: 'dfhdfh',
        slug: 'dfdfdh',
        dateadded: '2016-05-01T04:39:36.840Z',
        updateddate: null },
      { id: 'cinmhus6x0000mtrfubcw3eur',
        name: 'sdf',
        title: 'dfhsdfh',
        content: '`sdgdsgd',
        slug: 'dfhsdfh',
        dateadded: '2016-04-30T01:53:13.017Z',
        updateddate: null },
      { id: 'cinmgl1wv000140rf5fdizqsl',
        name: 'sdgsdg',
        title: 'fssddsg',
        content: 'fdfhdfh',
        slug: 'fssddsg',
        dateadded: '2016-04-30T01:17:39.439Z',
        updateddate: null } ]
    [ { id: 'cino38mfc0000mrrfdyn8v5k0',
        name: 'sdf',
        title: 'dfdfdh',
        content: 'dfhdfh',
        slug: 'dfdfdh',
        dateadded: '2016-05-01T04:39:36.840Z',
        updateddate: null },
      { id: 'cinmhus6x0000mtrfubcw3eur',
        name: 'sdf',
        title: 'dfhsdfh',
        content: '`sdgdsgd',
        slug: 'dfhsdfh',
        dateadded: '2016-04-30T01:53:13.017Z',
        updateddate: null },
      { id: 'cinmgl1wv000140rf5fdizqsl',
        name: 'sdgsdg',
        title: 'fssddsg',
        content: 'fdfhdfh',
        slug: 'fssddsg',
        dateadded: '2016-04-30T01:17:39.439Z',
        updateddate: null } ]
    [ { id: 'cino38mfc0000mrrfdyn8v5k0',
        name: 'sdf',
        title: 'dfdfdh',
        content: 'dfhdfh',
        slug: 'dfdfdh',
        dateadded: '2016-05-01T04:39:36.840Z',
        updateddate: null },
      { id: 'cinmhus6x0000mtrfubcw3eur',
        name: 'sdf',
        title: 'dfhsdfh',
        content: '`sdgdsgd',
        slug: 'dfhsdfh',
        dateadded: '2016-04-30T01:53:13.017Z',
        updateddate: null },
      { id: 'cinmgl1wv000140rf5fdizqsl',
        name: 'sdgsdg',
        title: 'fssddsg',
        content: 'fdfhdfh',
        slug: 'fssddsg',
        dateadded: '2016-04-30T01:17:39.439Z',
        updateddate: null } ]
```

UPDATE 2:
So I've implemented the reducers, actions, and sagas into a [ducks module](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux):

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { take, call, put, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';

// constants
const ADD_POST = 'ceres/post/ADD_POST';
const ADD_POST_REQUEST = 'ceres/post/sagas/ADD_POST_REQUEST';
const ADD_POSTS = 'ceres/post/ADD_POSTS';
const ADD_SELECTED_POST = 'ceres/post/ADD_SELECTED_POST';
const CHANGE_SELECTED_POST = 'ceres/post/CHANGE_SELECTED_POST';
const DELETE_POST_REQUEST = 'ceres/post/sagas/DELETE_POST_REQUEST';
const DELETE_POST = 'ceres/post/DELETE_POST';
const FETCH_POSTS = 'ceres/post/sagas/FETCH_POSTS';
const GET_POST = 'ceres/post/sagas/GET_POST';

// reducer
const initialState = fromJS({ posts: [], post: {} });

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_POST :
      return state.update('posts', posts => posts.unshift(action.payload));

    case ADD_POSTS :
      return state.set('posts', action.payload);

    case CHANGE_SELECTED_POST:
      return state.set('post', action.payload);

    case DELETE_POST :
      return state.update('posts', posts => posts.filter(post => post.get('id') !== action.payload.get('id')));

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// actions
function addPost(post) {
  return {
    type: ADD_POST,
    payload: fromJS({
      name: post.name,
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content,
      slug: post.slug,
      id: post.id,
      dateadded: post.dateadded,
      updateddate: post.updateddate,
    }),
  };
}

export function addPostRequest(post) {
  return {
    type: ADD_POST_REQUEST,
    post,
  };
}


export function addPosts(posts) {
  return {
    type: ADD_POSTS,
    payload: fromJS(posts),
  };
}

export function fetchPosts() {
  return {
    type: FETCH_POSTS,
  };
}

export function changeSelectedPost(post) {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_SELECTED_POST,
    payload: fromJS(post),
  };
}

export function getPostRequest(slug) {
  return {
    type: GET_POST,
    slug,
  };
}

export function deletePost(post) {
  return {
    type: DELETE_POST,
    payload: post,
  };
}

export function deletePostRequest(post) {
  return {
    type: DELETE_POST_REQUEST,
    post,
  };
}

// sagas
const baseURL = typeof window === 'undefined' ? process.env.BASE_URL || (`http://localhost:${(process.env.PORT || 5000)}`) : '';

function callApi(url, requestObj = {}) {
  return fetch(url, requestObj)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => response)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function *watchFetchPosts() {
  while (true) {
    yield take(FETCH_POSTS);
    yield fork(fetchPostsSaga);
  }
}

function *fetchPostsSaga() {
  const { posts } = yield call(callApi, `${baseURL}/api/getPosts`);
  yield put(addPosts(posts));
}

function *watchAddPostRequest() {
  while (true) {
    const { post } = yield take(ADD_POST_REQUEST);
    yield fork(addPostRequestSaga, post);
  }
}

function *addPostRequestSaga(newPost) {
  const { post } = yield call(callApi, `${baseURL}/api/addPost`, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      post: {
        name: newPost.name,
        title: newPost.title,
        content: newPost.content,
      },
    }),
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }),
  });
  yield put(addPost(post));
}

function *watchGetPostRequest() {
  while (true) {
    const { slug } = yield take(GET_POST);
    yield fork(getPostRequestSaga, slug);
  }
}

function *getPostRequestSaga(slug) {
  const { post } = yield call(callApi, `${baseURL}/api/getPost?slug=${slug}`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }),
  });
  yield put(changeSelectedPost(post));
}

function *watchDeletePostRequest() {
  while (true) {
    const { post } = yield take(DELETE_POST_REQUEST);
    yield fork(deletePostRequestSaga, post);
  }
}

function *deletePostRequestSaga(post) {
  yield [
    call(callApi, `${baseURL}/api/deletePost`, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        postId: post.get('id'),
      }),
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
    }),
    put(deletePost(post)),
  ];
}

export function *rootPostSaga() {
  yield [
    fork(watchFetchPosts),
    fork(watchAddPostRequest),
    fork(watchGetPostRequest),
    fork(watchDeletePostRequest),
  ];
}
```

and they all work as intended ON THE CLIENT side but not the server side :/ . My `configureStore.js` file currently looks like:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import reduxCatch from 'redux-catch';
import postReducer from './modules/post';

function errorHandler(error, getState) {
  console.error(error);
  console.debug('current state', getState());
}

function routeReducer(state = fromJS({ locationBeforeTransitions: null }), action) {
  if (action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE) {
    return state.merge({
      locationBeforeTransitions: action.payload,
    });
  }
  return state;
}

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

  const store = createStore(combineReducers({ postReducer, route: routeReducer }), initialState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, reduxCatch(errorHandler)),
    typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.devToolsExtension !== 'undefined' ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f,
  ));
  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('./modules/post', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('./modules/post'); //eslint-disable-line
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run; //eslint-disable-line
  return store;
}
```

So, I can run the rootPostSaga by running `store.runSaga(rootPostSaga)`. This works on the root file for my client-side code but I'm unsure where to put it for the server side I've tried placing it in both `server/server.js`:

```
// some code before and after not shown!
// Server Side Rendering based on routes matched by React-router.
app.use((req, res) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).end('Internal server error');
    }

    if (!renderProps) {
      return res.status(404).end('Not found!');
    }

    const initialState = fromJS({
      postReducer: {
        posts: [],
        post: {},
      },
      route: {
        locationBeforeTransitions: null,
      },
    });

    const store = configureStore(initialState);
    store.runSaga(rootPostSaga);

    fetchComponentData(store, renderProps.components, renderProps.params)
      .then(() => {
        const createElement = (Component, props) => (
          <Component
            {...props}
            radiumConfig={{ userAgent: req.headers['user-agent'] }}
          />
        );
        const initialView = renderToString(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <RouterContext {...renderProps} createElement={createElement} />
          </Provider>
        );
        const finalState = store.getState().toJS();

        res.status(200).end(renderFullPage(initialView, finalState, getFilename()));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.end(renderFullPage(`Error: ${err}`, {}, getFilename()));
      });
  });
});
```

and in `server/utils/fetchData` (the file which contains the function `fetchComponentData` for `server/server.js):

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
import { rootPostSaga } from '../../shared/redux/modules/post';


export function fetchComponentData(store, components, params) {
  store.runSaga(rootPostSaga);
  console.log('ran saga');
  const needs = components.reduce((prev, current) => {
    return (current.need || [])
      .concat((current.WrappedComponent ? current.WrappedComponent.need : []) || [])
      .concat(prev);
  }, []);
  const promises = needs.map(need => store.dispatch(need(params)));
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

both to no avail :/

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Have you been able to narrow down where the failure is happening with logs?

Comment: @ShaneCavaliere When the 'FETCH_POSTS' action is called when the app is being rendered server-side (this is an universal/isomorphic app), the following is returned (I know I'm doing something with the fork in fetchPosts wrong but I have no idea how to solve the issue): SEE ABOVE (the logs are too long to be in a comment :P)

Comment: ```fork``` is non-blocking, the middleware doesn't suspend the Generator while waiting for the result of the function you passed in. It invokes it, then resumes immediately.
Try updating the ```fetchPosts``` function, removing the fork and just using a regular ```call``` instead?